# How much use did the word 'delete' get before the technological boom?

Tags: etymology

For as long as I can remember, I've only used the word 'delete' in a technological context. I'm fairly certain, most kids--or the generation before them--know exactly what the word means.

Did this word get much use in other literary works?

Comment: You might try looking at Google Ngrams (http://books.google.com/ngrams).

Comment: @zpletan: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=delete&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=1

Comment: Another potentially misleading ngram there.  Many of the pre-computing hits come from errata, not normal usage of the word.

Answer (score 5):

Etymology online offers the following:

### [delete](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=delete&searchmode=none)

> late 15c., "destroy, eradicate," from L. deletus, pp. of delere
>   "destroy, blot out, efface," from delevi, originally perf. tense of
>   delinere "to daub, erase by smudging" (as of the wax on a writing
>   table), from de- "from, away" (see de-) + linere "to smear, wipe" (see
>   lime (1)). **In English, specifically of written matter, from c.1600.**
>   Related: Deleted; deleting.

(and related)

### dele

> typographer's direction to blot out a letter, from L. dele, imperative
>   singular of delere (see delete).

Comment: I think it was particularly used in relation to deleted **text** in the publishing and literary spheres before it really took off in the computing context.

Comment: The word _delete_ may have been around for centuries, but I believe the expression _control-alt-delete_ is relatively new. :^)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the ultimate origin of the word goes back to the Greek word "deleterion" (see current English word "deleterious" the meaning of which is disastrous, poisonous, eradicating).

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this please, just as the other answerer has indicated his source? We like to have substantiated answers rather than just answers that could be no more than mere opinion. Thanks.